# Creating a new character from a string in Swift

Tags: swift, string, character

This is a bit of a strange question. Would it be possible to create a new character in Swift from a string. Let's say that `"aa"` would be recognized as a separate character from `"a"`. The same way `"\n"` or `"\t"` are recognized as single characters even though strictly speaking they are made up of two other characters and when you iterate over a string containing them they will appear as single characters. Even if the solution to this is [janky](http://www.yourdictionary.com/janky) or weird it would save me a lot of time in what I'm doing.

Comment: I don’t know if there is a way to do this, but could you get what you need by using the `String.split()` or `String.replacingOccurences()` methods?

Comment: It would be useful to better explain what it is you are trying to do and why you wish to treat "aa" as a single character.

Answer (score 0):

In swift, you can convert string all characters into the set of characters like that and again into string:

```
let stringData : String = "aa"
var charactersSet = Set(stringData)// ["a"]

let finalResult = String(charactersSet)
/// output = "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Every instance of Swift’s Character type represents a single extended grapheme cluster. An extended grapheme cluster is a sequence of one or more Unicode scalars that (when combined) produce a single human-readable character.

Source: [Strings and Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html).

> The issues involved in determining and tailoring grapheme cluster boundaries are covered in detail in [Unicode Standard Annex #29](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries), which gives a number of examples and some algorithms.

Source: [Characters and Grapheme Clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html).

So the answer is “no.” You cannot change what Swift considers to be
a `Character`, that is defined by the Unicode standard and compiled
into the Swift runtime library.